# What is the time complexity of the following recursive code

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Not sure whether it is relevant or not but the problem that I am trying to solve is

~~~~~~~~~~~~~Shortest Distance from All Buildings~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

You want to build a house on an empty land which reaches all buildings in the shortest amount of distance. You can only move up, down, left and right. You are given a 2D grid of values 0, 1 or 2, where:

Each 0 marks an empty land which you can pass by freely.
Each 1 marks a building which you cannot pass through.
Each 2 marks an obstacle which you cannot pass through.

Find the smallest distance from an empty land that can access all buildings
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Although my solution is working correctly on small inputs it is timing out for larger inputs due to a large time complexity.

However I am unsure about the exact time complexity of this solution and want to correctly understand what is the time complexity of this solution so that I can try to improve it if possible.

I am pretty sure that the time complexity of the outer loop is O(MN)(M is the total num of rows and N is total num of cols) because we are looping over all the position of the grid but what I am unsure about is the time complexity of the recursive shortDist method. Is it O(MN) as well because in worst case it will touch every position of the grid and therefore the total time complexity of this solution will be O(M^2 * N^2) or is it something else, If so it would be great if some one can explain me about it.

My solution is

```
class Solution {
public:
    int shortestDistance(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {

        vector<std::pair<int,int>> dir = {{-1,0}, {1,0}, {0,-1}, {0,1}};
        // pair(row, col) -> distance
        map<std::pair<int,int>, int> cache;
        vector<vector<bool>> visited(grid.size(), vector<bool>(grid[0].size(), false)); // to check if we have already visited that location on the grid
        int minDist = INT_MAX;
        int maxCount =0;
        // Finding number of 1's
        for(int i =0; i< grid.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int y =0; y < grid[0].size(); y++)
            {
                if(grid[i][y] == 1)
                {
                    maxCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        // For each 0 find the distance of each 1's and their count
        // if the count of 1's is less than the number of 1's in the
        // grid that grid position is not an acceptable pos
        for(int i =0; i< grid.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int y =0; y < grid[0].size(); y++)
            {
                if(grid[i][y] == 0)
                {
                    shortDist(grid, cache, dir, visited, i, y, 0);
                    int dist =0;
                    int count = cache.size();// number of 1's
                    if(count == maxCount)
                    {
                        // if we are here it implies that the empty land space have path to all the buildings
                        for(auto iter = cache.begin(); iter != cache.end(); iter++)
                        {
                            dist += iter->second;
                        }
                        if(dist < minDist)
                        {
                            minDist = dist;
                        }
                    }
                    cache.clear();
                }       
            }
        }

        return minDist == INT_MAX ? -1 : minDist;

    }

    void shortDist(vector<vector<int>>& grid, map<std::pair<int,int>, int>& cache, vector<std::pair<int,int>>& dir, vector<vector<bool>>& visited, int row, int col, int dist)
    {
        if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= grid.size() || col >= grid[0].size())
        {
            return;
        }
        if(grid[row][col] == 2)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(grid[row][col] == 1)
        {
            auto found = cache.find(make_pair(row, col));
            if(found == cache.end())
            {
                cache[(make_pair(row, col))] = dist;
            }
            else
            {
                found->second = min(found->second, dist);
            }

            return;
        }

        if(visited[row][col])
        {
            return;
        }

        visited[row][col] = true;
        for(int i =0; i < dir.size(); i++)
        {
            int newRow = row + dir[i].first;
            int newCol = col + dir[i].second;
            shortDist(grid, cache, dir, visited, newRow, newCol, dist+1);
        }
        visited[row][col] = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: it would be good if people who have qownvoted please point out what they felt missing or inappropriate, because i truly feel that this is a genuine doubt and I have clearly done my research and have even provided what I think might be the answer with explanation. Atleast I would like to know what more info can I provide next time to make things more clear.

Comment: If you can only go through 0's and need to access all the buildings, then there should be a network of 0's connected. Maybe it boils down to Dijkstra's algorithm once the paths are known.

Comment: I would suggest that you add algorithm tag as well to your question.

Comment: Basically I am starting from a 0 and going in all four direction till I find a 1. Once I find a 1, I am storing row and col  of the 1 and the distance in a map. Since the same 1 might be found later having a shorter distance, I am updating the distance in this case. After checking the distance of all the once, if number of 1 found is the same as the total number of 1's in the grid , I am checking and updating the distance id smaller. Ok I will add the algorithm tags as well.

Comment: Might be more suitable for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the `shortDist` is the major contributor.

The function `shortDist` has for the `find` a O(log(MN)) as the cache can max contain rows * cols entries, (using `std::map`, using `std::unordered_map` is only O(1) if you have a perfect hash function). Then you recurse for distance which is D = max(M,N), in reality you visit every MN points. for a total of O(MN log(MN)) for each call from `shortestDistance`.

In `shortestDistance` The second looping over the grid has O(MN) for the first two loops and then O(MN) for looping over the cache, giving O(M^2*N^2), the call to shortDist is O(M^2N^2 log(MN)).

You can save the log(MN) if you use another array of MN to directly lookup the value.

Implementation optimizations.

Your call to shortDist has way too many parameters.

The `dir` vector should be a constexpr std::array as it never changes and is used in all searches.

`Cache` and `visited` should be members of the class, that shortestDistance resets for each call, if not the instance of Solution is used only once.

Dragging grid with you as a parameter also seems wasteful considering how many times you do it. Making it a class ref or copy would solve this.

Then `shortDist` only has a reasonable 3 parameters.

You can save a lot of performance loss by making the grid one dimensional and calculate the index your self, reducing every x,y lookup from two to one memory access in `shortDist`.

Comment: You are correct surt i was assuming find to be O(1) but that is only the case when you have a perfect hash and the worst time complexity might be different. One question though you stated above that it is O(log(MN)) but if the hash bucket is a linkedList won't the worst time complexity be O(MN) and not O(log(MN)) and we would have to search all the element to find the element.

Comment: I assume a std::map for the log(MN), as the std::unordered_map would be worst case MN.

Comment: But as i said you can replace the map with a grid of the same size as the grid for O(1) which for all practical purpose would be a perfect has, namely 1:1.